# how to correctly pass around function as parameters?

Tags: functions, quote, symbols

I have a working snippet that advices both kill-buffer and kill-this-buffer to not kill the *scratch* buffer:

```
  (defun ninrod/scratch-bodyguard (buffer-assassin &rest arguments)
    (let ((buffer-to-kill (buffer-name (current-buffer))))
      (if (equal buffer-to-kill "*scratch*")
          (message "DENIED! don't kill my precious *scratch*!!")
        (apply buffer-assassin arguments))))
  (defun ninrod/scratch-protection (buffer-assassin &rest arguments)
    (let ((buffer-to-kill (car arguments)))
      (if (equal buffer-to-kill "*scratch*")
          (message "DENIED! don't kill my precious *scratch*!!")
        (apply buffer-assassin arguments))))
  (advice-add #'kill-this-buffer :around #'ninrod/scratch-bodyguard)
  (advice-add #'kill-buffer :around #'ninrod/scratch-protection)
```

The problem is that these lines:

```
  (message "DENIED! don't kill my precious *scratch*!!")
 (apply buffer-assassin arguments))))
```

Are repeated in both functions, so I thought that I could apply the DRY principle and refactor the snippet to this:

```
(defun ninrod--protection (buffer-assassin buffer-to-kill &rest arguments)
  (if (equal buffer-to-kill "*scratch*")
      (message "DENIED! don't kill my precious *scratch*!!")
    (apply buffer-assassin arguments)))
(defun ninrod/scratch-bodyguard (buffer-assassin &rest arguments)
  (let ((buffer-to-kill (buffer-name (current-buffer))))
    (ninrod--protection 'buffer-assassin buffer-to-kill arguments)))
(defun ninrod/scratch-protection (buffer-assassin &rest arguments)
  (let ((buffer-to-kill (car arguments)))
    (ninrod--protection 'buffer-assassin buffer-to-kill arguments)))
(advice-add #'kill-this-buffer :around #'ninrod/scratch-bodyguard)
(advice-add #'kill-buffer :around #'ninrod/scratch-protection)
```

This causes all hell to break loose. Now I can't even close emacs, because apparently emacs tries to kill all buffers
and as I've just tampered with the kill buffer functions, well, it's bad. Very bad.

I know I mean well, but I'm must be doing something very stupid. For starters, I don't know if I can really pass around
functions as parameters? So it could be that?

How would you refactor that snippet to apply the dry principle?

edit:

this works:

```
(defun ninrod--protection (buffer-assassin buffer-to-kill &rest arguments)
  (if (equal buffer-to-kill "*scratch*")
      (message "DENIED! don't kill my precious *scratch*!!")
    (apply buffer-assassin arguments)))

(defun ninrod/scratch-bodyguard (buffer-assassin &rest arguments)
  (let ((buffer-to-kill (buffer-name (current-buffer))))
    (ninrod--protection 'buffer-assassin buffer-to-kill arguments)))

(advice-add #'kill-this-buffer :around #'ninrod/scratch-bodyguard)
```

so the problem lies exactly here:

```
(defun ninrod/scratch-protection (buffer-assassin &rest arguments)
  (let ((buffer-to-kill (car arguments)))
    (ninrod--protection 'buffer-assassin buffer-to-kill arguments)))
```

edit2: quoting or unquoting the function `buffer-assassin` does not make a difference

Comment: Regarding edit2: It does make a difference. Quoted, you get a `Symbol's function definition is void: buffer-assassin` error, unquoted it's `Wrong type arguments: stringp, (#<buffer whatever>)`. The second error is due to the `&rest` that @YoungFrog mentioned. As he/she said, there are different types of hell.

Comment: Yes, I should have stated the error I was getting, thank you

Comment: When that happen to me I do  [`Cx-b` `*scratch*` `RET`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234963/re-open-scratch-buffer-in-emacs) to recreate the `*scratch*` buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't quote `buffer-assassin` when passing it to `ninrod--protection`. In your advice-functions, `buffer-assassin` is a variable, the value of which is the originial function. When you pass it quoted, `buffer-assassin` in `ninrod--protection` will have the value `'buffer-assassin` (i.e. the symbol itself), so `apply` will try calling a (global) function named like that, not the value of the caller's local variable.

Edit: A somewhat cleaner solution (i.e. without advising) would be

```
(add-to-list 'kill-buffer-query-functions 
  (lambda () (not (eq (current-buffer) (get-buffer "*scratch*")))))
```

Comment: that's nice, but unquoting `buffer-assassin` sill causes all hell to break loose.

Comment: I guess removing &rest in your ninrod--protection function will help. Problem is 'arguments' is transmitted as a list, and &rest makes it a list of a list.

Comment: Additionally hell can break loose in so many ways. It would be nice to include the error message or a backtrace when that happens.

Comment: @YoungFrog, removing &rest from the ninrod--protection function fixed the problem!

Comment: Additionally, you should make sure to actually make `buffer-to-kill` a string in `ninrod/scratch-protection`, as `kill-buffer` may also be called on a buffer directly, which makes your comparison to `"*scratch*"` fail. Try `(kill-buffer (get-buffer "*scratch*"))` to see where things go wrong.

Comment: @ninrod I think ChrisR's answer is correct. No need for another one.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the code, go with ChrisRs answer.

You can definitely pass around functions, but you do it indirectly by passing the symbol the function is stored in. When you write:

(f 'myfunction)

You are passing the symbol `'myfunction` as an argument to the function f. Specifically when you intend to pass a symbol in order to pass a function, you should actually write `#'myfunction` because that hints to emacs you're intending to pass a function and you get better error messages. Emacs is a lisp-2, meaning that a single symbol can hold both a variable value and a function value, but generally if a function takes a "function" as an argument, it will assume that for the symbol you pass in you intend to use the function value associated with it, not the variable value, and will extract it for you.

Comment: I think it's the other way around: the original function is stored in the value slot of the advice's first parameter. That's why the `apply` in the original implementation works.

Comment: @ChrisR oops, yes you are correct