# Void Function Error

Tags: org-mode, quote

The following function is meant to call an arbitrary function at each of the immediate children of an org heading:

```
(defun org-map-shallow-tree (funcarg)
  ""
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading)    
    (let* ((cur-level (car (org-heading-components))))
      (org-map-tree (lambda () (when (equal (+ 1 cur-level) (car (org-heading-components)))
                                     (funcall 'funcarg)))))))
```

The problem is that when I call it, as in:

```
(defun lol () (message "lol"))
(org-map-shallow-tree 'lol)
```

I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function funcarg)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to correctly pass around function as parameters?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/how-to-correctly-pass-around-function-as-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a stray quote in your code:

```
(defun org-map-shallow-tree (funcarg)
  ""
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading)    
    (let* ((cur-level (car (org-heading-components))))
      (org-map-tree (lambda () (when (equal (+ 1 cur-level) (car (org-heading-components)))
                                     (funcall funcarg))))))) ; <= Don't quote funcarg
```

You passed a function symbol via `funcarg`, and you want
`funcall` to call that function, i.e., the *content* of
`funcarg`, not the `funcarg` symbol itself.