# Why funcall doesn't work from a closure

Tags: closures, funcall

I'm having difficulty to call a function passed as an argument. 
Why the following snippet doesn't work, and how can I make it work?

`lexical-binding` is set to `t`

```
(defun on-success (data)
  (print "This works!")
  (print data))

(defun send-req (url callback)
  (request url
   :success (function*
             (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
               (print (type-of callback)    ; <- this prints 'symbol', without lexical binding it would be nil
               (funcall 'callback data)))))

(defun foo ()
  (send-req
   "https://google.com"
   'on-success))

(foo)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Void Function Error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/void-function-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote `callback` here:

```
(funcall 'callback data)
```

Quoted, you've said to call the function *named* "callback" (i.e. using the function slot of the `callback` symbol).

What you want to do is call the function in the *value* of the `callback` argument:

```
(funcall callback data)
```

Comment: Yup, you are right. Thank you! Also while testing I learned that if `funcall` doesn't apply the correct number of args, it just won't work at all either.